# Как правильно определить псевдоним шаблонной структуры?

Tags: typedef, c++, c++11

Определяю узел дерева

```
template<typename KeyType,typename ItemType> struct __Node__{
KeyType key;
ItemType item;
list<__Node__*> childs;
};
```

Хочу дать структуре псевдоним:

```
template<typename KeyType,typename ItemType> using Node = struct __Node__<KeyType, ItemType>;
```

Но не выходит. Как правильно пользоваться таким механизмом, чтобы вышло что-то похожее на это:

```
typedef struct __Node__<KeyType, ItemType> Node<KeyType, ItemType>;
```

?

Comment: А какой у вас компилятор?

Вот документация: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias

Comment: @OlegUP, какая ошибка? С g++ 4.8.2 ваш пример отлично компилируется.

Answer (score 1):

Вот так надо. Указывайте готовые типы при создании псевдонимов, чтоб компилятор не лез в пустоту.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<list>

using namespace std;

template<typename KeyType,typename ItemType>
class A{
public:
    KeyType key;
    ItemType item;
    list<A*> l;
};

typedef A<int, int> myStructInt; // здесь нужно указывать аргументы
typedef A<char, char> myStructChar; // и здесь тоже самое
typedef A<int, char> myStruct1, myStruct2; // и здесь тоже самое

int main(){

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Увы, это не то, что нужно.

Comment: Видимо, без спецификации для конкрктного нельзя такой механизм заюзать...

Answer (score 0):

В общем, вопрос был задан потому, что вместо например:

```
void myclass::f(struct Node<T>* node) {}
```

Написать:

```
void myclass::f(_Node<T>* node) {}
```

но все срабатывает и без ключевого слова struct(по крайней мере в объявлении класса)
я теперь сделал так:

.h файл:

```
using namespace std;
template<typename KeyType,typename ItemType> struct Node{
    KeyType key;
    ItemType item;
    list<shared_ptr<Node> > childs;
};

template<typename KeyType,typename ItemType> class Tree {
public:
    typedef Node<KeyType, ItemType> _Node;  !!!
private:
    shared_ptr<_Node> root;

public:
    shared_ptr<_Node> find(KeyType key, shared_ptr<_Node> parent=0);
    ...
};
```

.cpp файл:

```
template<typename KeyType, typename ItemType>
    shared_ptr<_Node> Tree<KeyType, ItemType>::find(KeyType key, shared_ptr<_Node> parent) {...}
```

main.cpp:

```
Tree<int, string> tree;
```